# Smallest lowest cost way to isolate RGMII signals between devices on the same CCA?

Tags: ethernet, isolation, digital-isolator, rgmii

I have a single Gigabit Ethernet line coming out of a circuit card.  Access to the line will be shared by two CPUs.  To facilitate shared access, the CCA will have an Ethernet switch IC.

The switch IC connects to the processors and the PHY going to the external line via [RGMII](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303171328/http://www.hp.com/rnd/pdfs/RGMIIv2_0_final_hp.pdf).  The switch IC datasheet says that it supports directly connecting the RGMII on the processors without a PHY or magnetics.

[image]

Both the processors and the switch IC share a common ground plane, but other than that I want each of the three components to be as isolated as possible from each other.

Ideally, if one of the other unrelated external connections for one of the CPUs experienced a fault and got shorted to say ±100V on a transient basis, I would want the PHY and the other processor to be unaffected (other than loosing communications with the destroyed CPU).

**What is smallest lowest cost way to connect the CPUs to the PHY while maintaining isolation in case of a power supply fault?**

- Note that the RGMII signals will only have to travel like 3~4 inches max between each chip.
- Note that each CPU and the switch IC have their own power supplies, but all devices do share a common ground plane.

1. I know the obvious answer is that Ethernet provides isolation.  So, I could just put a PHY on all three ports of the switch IC and on the processors and then use standard Ethernet transformers for the isolation.  The upside is that its pretty much guaranteed to work.  The downside is that this solution is big and expensive because it uses five PHY chips instead of one and three transformers instead of one.

[image]

2. Another option would be to use a digital isolator IC.

- Analog Devices has their [iCoupler](https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/standard-digital-isolators.html) isolators that go as high as 150Mbps.
- Silicon Labs/Skyworks makes their [Si86xx](https://www.skyworksinc.com/Products/Isolation/Si86xx-Digital-Isolators#:~:text=Si86xx%20digital%20isolators%20are%20the,operation%20in%20harsh%20industrial%20applications.) capacitive isolators that go up to 150Mbps
- Texas Instruments have [capacitive type isolators](https://www.ti.com/isolation/digital-isolators/products.html) that goes to 150Mbps.
- NVE makes the [IL800 series](https://www.nve.com/IsolatorProducts) GMR isolators that work up to 110Mbps.

I have used the isolators from all these vendors and they work well.  But RGMII can have a clock rate as high as 125MHz, and data clocked on both edges (so 250Mbps).  Since the isolators I know of only go to 150Mbps I can't use them.  The RX and TX sides of RGMII appear to be independent and unidirectional (so no round trip timing implications?).  In that case a 6-channel digital isolator with good channel to channel matching might work.  Still I am not entirely sure that a 5~10ns propagation delay won't break RGMII somehow.

[image]

3. The last option I considered is just using a 10K 0805 resistor and 10nF NP0 250V 0805 capacitor in parallel on each data line.  The capacitor would pass high frequency signals and the resistor would provide DC correctness.  In the event of a fault the resistor and capacitor won't pass any significant DC current into the Ethernet Switch IC.  I have done capacitive isolation for 100Mbps DC balanced signals before.  But RGMII isn't DC balanced, so it's a bit of a risk.  I will have to use source series termination on the traces (not shown, but probably fine).  I suppose I might just have to simulate or bread-board this one.

[image]

I would like to know if anyone can confirm (based on practical experience or theory) that one of my existing ideas will  work, or has any better options.

Comment: I think you know the answer already…….

Comment: @Kartman Possibly, but I would like to have someone confirm it.

Comment: What about using a 1GHz 3dB splitter with isolation

Comment: Can you support GMII (not reduced) for the two horizontal links in your diagram?  Twice the number of data pins means isolators only need half the bandwidth.